# How to define macro bases on macro value?

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

I have macros:

```
#if defined DEBUG  &&  DEBUG
#  define D(...) printf(__VA_ARGS__)
#else
#  define D(...)
#endif
```

Which effectively do nothing when `DEBUG` has `TRUE` value.

But now I want to provide the `TYPE` thing. Which will show the type of debugging:

```
D( 1, "some string" );
D( 2, "another thing" );
```

Is there a way to define such macros which will do nothing for `D(1,..)` and print debug messages for `D(2,...)` when `DEBUG` is `2` and viceversa when `1`?

I wanna something like this::

```
#if defined DEBUG  &&  DEBUG
#  define D(type,...) if DEBUG&type THEN printf(__VA_ARGS__) else do nothing
#else
#  define D(...)
#endif
```

Comment: Will that be literal "1" and literal "2" or any placeholders evaluating to 1 or 2?

Comment: @Yunnosch: It maybe `3` which means `0b11` and print both messages

Comment: Still not clear. Will it be a literally `1` or `2` or `3` or it will be a variable/expression having this value?

Comment: @EugeneSh.: We can provide flags: `D( DUMP_thing1 | DUMP_thing2 )`. where `DUMP_thing1 is 0b01` and `DUMP_thing2 is 0b10`

Comment: @EugenKonkov Then it won't be possible in compile time.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: It's possible, but one has to write an exhaustive list of combinations, which is far beyond unwieldy. See clebanc's answer below for a start.

Comment: @Deduplicator I have written a similar answer to the one clebanc did and left it as a draft until the clarification above. Clearly this is not what the OP would really want.

Comment: I would recommend using incremental logging levels (info, warn, debug, error, ...) rather than `or'ing` them together

Comment: @EugeneSh.: May you please post example for literal case?

Comment: @EugenKonkov  cleblanc already did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it won't be truely evaluated at preprocessing time, but if the type is a compile-time-constant, still at compile-type.

```
#define D(type, ...) (void)((type & DEBUG) && fprintf(stderr, __VA_ARGS__))
```

The above needs at least C99 though.

Comment: Interesting, but I do not want macros which expand to code

Comment: @EugenKonkov: If you really insist on evaluating it at compile-time, then the first argument to `D()` *must* be a decimal literal, and you have to write code for every theretic combination of flags, in clebanc's style. That's ridiculously far beyond unwieldy, but it *can* be done. Consider writing a program to write those out for you to save your sanity.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this;

```
#if defined DEBUG  
#  define P1(...) 
#  define P2(...) printf(__VA_ARGS__)
#  define D(n, ...) P##n(__VA_ARGS__)
#else
#  define D(...)
#endif

main()
{
    D(1, "Test");
    D(2, "Test2");
}
```

Comment: And if this approach is taken, there is no need in numbers at all. Just use some descriptive names.

Answer (score 0):

This did not resolve the problem but take me closer. Maybe it will be useful for someone:

```
#define _CAT(a, ...) a ## __VA_ARGS__

#define CHECK(...) SECOND(__VA_ARGS__, 0)
#define SECOND(x, n, ...) n

#define _NOT_0 _TRUE()
#define _TRUE() ~, 1

#define BOOL(x) NOT(NOT(x))
#define NOT(x) CHECK(_CAT(_NOT_, x))

#define IF(cond) _IF(BOOL(cond))
#define _IF(cond) _CAT(_IF_, cond)
#define _IF_1(...) __VA_ARGS__
#define _IF_0(...)

IF(1)(printf("YES\n");)
IF(0)(printf("NO\n");)
```

Links to tricks: [first](https://github.com/pfultz2/Cloak/wiki/C-Preprocessor-tricks,-tips,-and-idioms) and [second](http://jhnet.co.uk/articles/cpp_magic). Second link is more interesting because it describes what is coming on step-by-step